# android unable to upload image to server

Tags: android, image, server

I am a neophyte to android.since last couple of days I am facing some problem to send my image to server. I simply have a form that include some textfields and image to be taken from library.Everything is working perfect except image upload.I tried most of tutorials on google.The main problem is logcat is not showing any error.I am unable to track what actually went wrong.
This is what I did

I used this code to get Image from galary

```
 private void showFileChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }

 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            filePath = data.getData();
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                schoolLogoUpload.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

I wrote this function to send selected image to server

```
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String document_id = cursor.getString(0);
        document_id = document_id.substring(document_id.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
        cursor.close();

        cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " = ? ", new String[]{document_id}, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
        cursor.close();

        return path;
    }


public void uploadMultipart() {
        //getting the actual path of the image
        String path = getPath(filePath);

        //Uploading code
        try {
            String uploadId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

            //Creating a multi part request
            new MultipartUploadRequest(this, uploadId, UPLOAD_URL)
                    .addFileToUpload(path, "image") //Adding file
                    .setNotificationConfig(new UploadNotificationConfig())
                    .setMaxRetries(2)
                    .startUpload(); //Starting the upload

        } catch (Exception exc) {
            Toast.makeText(this, exc.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

This is my code to receive my image data at server side

```
if(Input::hasFile('image')) {
            $file = Input::file('image');
            $destination_path = "uploads";
            $extension = Input::file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $file_name = str_random(20). "." . $extension;
            Input::file('image')->move($destination_path, $file_name);
        }else{
            return \Response::json([
                "error"=>["message"=>"Please select the college logo"]
            ], 404);
```

Comment: Where are you calling `uploadMultipart()`?

Comment: You would also like to add `exc.printStackTrace()` to your method.

Comment: @mad_manny  I am calling that function inside my button that send data to a server.Can u help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you have converted an image to `Base64` format. Basically `Base64` format converts an image (or encodes an image) to the `String` format.

*** Write an `Asynctask` that will upload an image to the server for you ***

Below is the `Asynctask` :-

```
private class AsyncUploadToServer extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
    ProgressDialog pdUpload;

    String imageData = "";

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pdUpload = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pdUpload.setMessage("Uploading...");
        pdUpload.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        imageData = params[0];
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // URL where data to be uploaded
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(YOUR_URL_HERE);

        try
        {
            // adding data
            List<NameValuePair> dataToBeAdd = new ArrayList<>();
            dataToBeAdd.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uploadedImage", imageData));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToBeAdd));

            // execute http post request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            Log.i("MainActivity", "Response: " + response);
        }
        catch (ClientProtocolException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        pdUpload.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image Uploaded Successfully..!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you. :-)

P.S.:- If you don't know much about asynctask, here is the link https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: sir where should I add this code.Do I have to replace my above code with this or is this a complete code that allows me to upload my image to server.Please help

Comment: yeah you can replace your code with this. You just have to call this asynctask on button click event.

Comment: I wonder how to call a class inside a button.The next thing is how my selected image is connected to your above suggested class.

Comment: Basically you have to execute that asynctask on button click event with image as a parameter. Your image will be in String format after encoding it using Base64 format. Just read about Asynctask & how to pass values to it. Also how to execute asynctask on button click.

Comment: But I dont mean to send an image using base64.I wish to send image without using base64 encoder

Comment: what is the datatype you are using to store image in database table?

Comment: I wish to store the path of my image in string form at my database table

Comment: But in your code, you are getting an image path from MediaStore i.e. from gallery right?

Comment: ya,cant i just store image path to database

Comment: That would be a bad practice. Instead you convert image into Base64 & then store into database. So that you can retrieve the same image later from another device also. Converting image into Base64 is very easy. Just google it. ;)

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help and support.I got my problem fixed.Happy coding